# How to go back to a point of code within a While True Loop in python?

Tags: python

I need my input 3 to be validated, therefore it needs to return back to input 3 if the "else block" is activated. also "if block" must go back to input 1 thats why ive put continue.

```
while True:
    input 1
    input 2
      process
    input 3
       if result == "c';
             continue

       elif result == "e"
             break

       else:
           the code needs return back to input 3 until user enters "c" or "e"
```

How can implement this using python?

Comment: `input` X` is not valid python. What do you intend? To go back, you would use another loop and check result.

Comment: unable to use another loop as the continue statement in the "if block" needs to belong to the initial while true loop @user19077881

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you please elaborate with an example flow? You can also put actually code for your input variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flag variable to cope with nested loops. Such as:

```
flag = True
while flag == True:
    input('1')
    input('2')
    while True:
        result = input('3')
        if result == 'c':
            break
        elif result == 'e':
            flag= False
            break
        else:
            continue
```